# New Snapping while editing vertex's in ArcEngine 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine, editing, vertices

Is it possible to use the new (not classic) snapping functionality when editing the vertices of a polygon feature in ArcEngine 10. I would like editing vertices to behave exactly the same as editing vertices in ArcMap.

I know that with ArcEngine you pretty much have to control everything. So when we are creating the polygon we use the following function to capture the new snapped point using the snapping feedback object.

Is there some events I can tap into that'll allow me to tap into the editing vertices and update the mouse pointer to a snapped location?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates a point to a snapped point
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="currentPoint"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IPoint UpdateSnappedPoint(IPoint currentPoint)
    {
        ISnappingResult snapResult = null;
        IPoint point = currentPoint;

        if (_snapEnabled && _snappingFeedBack != null)
        {
            snapResult = _snappingEnvironment.PointSnapper.Snap(point);
            _snappingFeedBack.Update(snapResult, 0);
        }

        if (snapResult != null)
            point = snapResult.Location;

        return point;
    }
```

Niroshan

Answer (score 3):

There is a great chapter in concept and samples explaining editing in ArcGIS Engine: [ArcGIS Engine editing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/ArcGIS_Engine_editing/00010000009v000000/) and [How to work with the snap environment](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_work_with_the_snap_environment/00010000024s000000/)